# Is there a way of ignoring all values until a certain date

Tags: prometheus, grafana

An metrics I'm observing was incorrect until a certain date. Is there anyway in grafana, with a prometheus source, to ignore all values until that date? Just as if the metric was renamed (but renaming it is unfortunately not possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query like this

```
my_metric
and on() (
  (day_of_month() > 10 and month() == 7 and year() == 2023)
  or (month() > 7 and year() == 2023)
  or year() > 2023
)
```

to exclude all metric values before 2023.07.11.

It utilizes functions [`day_of_month()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#days_in_month), [`month()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#month) and [`year()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#year) of Prometheus to filter out values with inappropriate related values. Also notice, since mentioned functions produce vector without labels, we are using construct `and on()` to match them with original metric.

If you need to cut value not on the midnight, you can add a couple more lines with [`hour()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#hour) and [`minute()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#minute) functions.

---

Alternatively, if you have a timestamp of first moment when your metric become correct, you can use query

```
my_metric and timestamp(my_metric) > 1688080414
```

Where 1688080414 is a mentioned epoch timestamp.